# Cookies not being set in browser when making API request from React, but work with Django REST framework

Tags: reactjs, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

When I use the Django REST framework to send a POST request to the login endpoint, the cookies are added to the response, and I can observe them in the browser. Additionally, **I can confirm that I'm receiving the correct data (user ID and password) in both cases**.

However, when I use my React application to send the same POST request to the login endpoint, the cookies are not being added to the response, and consequently, they aren't stored in the browser. **Again, I receive the correct data (user ID and password) in this scenario as well**.

My django rest code :

```
 @api_view(['POST'])
def loginUser(request):
    print("request", request.data)
    id_Patient = int(request.data.get('id_Patient'))
    print("id_Patient", id_Patient)
    password = request.data.get('password')
    print("password", password)
    user = Patient.objects.filter(id_Patient=id_Patient).first()

    if user is None:
        print("user is None")
        return JsonResponse({"message": "User not found"}, status=404)

    if not user.check_password(password):
        print("not user.check_password(password)")
        return JsonResponse({"message": "Incorrect password"}, status=400)

    payload = {
        'id_Patient': user.id_Patient,
        'exp': datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=60),
        'iat': datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    }

    secret_key = os.urandom(32).hex()
    token = jwt.encode(payload, secret_key, algorithm='HS256')

    response = JsonResponse({"token": token})

    response.set_cookie('my_cookie', 'my_value', httponly=True)  # Set the cookie

    return response
```

What Actually Resulted:
Surprisingly, the cookies are being set correctly when I test the API request using Django's REST framework, and I'm receiving the expected user ID and password data in both scenarios. However, when I make the same request from my React app, the cookies are not being added to the response, and they are not stored in the browser.

This discrepancy has left me puzzled about why the cookies are behaving differently when the API request is made from my React app compared to when I use Django's REST framework for testing. I'm seeking insights or suggestions to understand the underlying cause of this behavior. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would advice you to use jwt token for the react app with django-rest-framework instead of cookies-base authentication

Answer (score 0):

in react app did you add `credentials:'include'`

```
fetch('your-api-url', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
  credentials: 'include', // Include cookies in the request
})
```

Comment: Yes i did it, I fixed the problem by taking a different approach